# Child item in TreeView not updating

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0, treeview

I copied the basic method of having checkbox in a treeview from the official Silverlight toolkit [Checkboxes in a TreeView example](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html?path=Controls|TreeView|Using%20CheckBoxes).

When a user clicks on a parent TreeViewItem I want all of the child items to be checked, as in the above example.  This works fine when the parent is collapsed, clicking the checkbox puts a tick in the parent and when you expand the node all children have a tick in the checkbox.

However it doesn't work if the parent is expanded.  None of the children are updated to have a tick in the checkbox, although the underlying data list is updated.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contracts}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}">
        <CheckBox IsTabStop="False" IsThreeState="{Binding Path=HasContracts}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Tag="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <sdk:TreeView x:Name="tvClientContract" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClientContracts, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
```

This is bound to a `List<ClientContract>` and uses the same code behind as in the linked example.

The ClientContract object is:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<ClientContract> Contracts { get; set; }
public bool? Selected { get; set; }
```

How can I force the child to repaint itself as the underlying `List<ClientContract>` object is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use INotifyPropertyChange(what I did instead of using ObservableCollection) here is how you do it per example on the ID element:

```
public class myclass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id_Value;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id_Value; }
        set
        {
            id_Value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClientContract> Contracts { get; set; }
    public bool? Selected { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

I hope this helps if it was what you were trying to do.

Comment: I was raising a NotifyPropertyChanged event on the collection as a whole, not the individual properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ObservableCollection<ClientContract>` instead of a `List<>`. Usually you want to databind to this collection type instead when the data is dynamic so it can notify the UI of collection changes.

Comment: Just tried it, no difference I'm afraid. I'm implementing INotifyPropertyChange within my VM.  As I said the value in the actual List is being set, it's just that the UI isn't updating.